# How to install Nlog in Portable xamarin code?

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, nlog

I have my project created in Protable code mode and i wish to install  NLog package to it but its not working. I'm getting following error:
Could not install NLog package into a project that targets '.NetPoratble,Version=4.5,Profile=Profile111'. Can anyone tell me how to counter this error?or is there any other way around for it?

Comment: Convert your PCL-based library to a NetStd2.0 one.

Comment: Hi bro,have you solved this porblem ? : )

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55488453/cannot-load-nlog-config-in-xamarin ?

Answer (score 0):

As SushiHangover said , you need to **Convert a Portable Class Library to .NET Standard**.

1. Unload your PCL project (*right click -> unload*), and start editing
   it (*right -> click edit*)
2. Delete Everything in the csproj and insert this:

   [image]
3. Add back NuGets (*simply open packages.config, and add the package
   references above, or via the NuGet package manager*).
4. Delete AssemblyInfo.cs (*this is now in the csproj*) and
   packages.config (*also in csproj via PackageReference*)

Here is [an article](https://xamarinhelp.com/upgrade-pcl-net-standard-class-library/) for reference.