# Cannot load nlog.config in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, logging, nlog

I cannot read **nlog.config** file in asset folder of android platform

```
NLog.LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration("NLog.config");
```

How to read nlog file and also this file is in android asset.

Answer (score 2):

You can also make use of Xamarin resource. Put the NLog.config file into the library project, then edit file's properties - change the build action to embedded resource.

```
public static Stream GetEmbeddedResourceStream(Assembly assembly, string resourceFileName)
{
  var resourcePaths = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
    .Where(x => x.EndsWith(resourceFileName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .ToList();
  if (resourcePaths.Count == 1)
  {
    return assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePaths.Single());
  }
  return null;
}

var nlogConfigFile = GetEmbeddedResourceStream(myAssembly, "NLog.config");
if (nlogConfigFile != null)
{
    var xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(nlogConfigFile);
    NLog.LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(xmlReader, null);
}
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Explicit-NLog-configuration-loading#loading-nlog-configuration-from-xamarin-resource

Comment: what does myAssembly stands for?

Comment: The assembly for the project that has the resources. Ex. `typeof(Program).Assembly`

Answer (score 1):

you could also try to use this (**nlog.config** file with a Build Action as an AndroidAsset):

```
NLog.LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration (XmlTextReader.Create(Assets.Open ("NLog.config")), null);
```

refer to:
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/Config/LoggingConfigurationFileLoader.cs#L101-L120

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extension  method to your context class that gets you the required asset as a stream:

```
 public static class Utils
 {
   public static Stream GetFromAssets(this Context context, string assetName)
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = context.Assets;
        Stream inputStream;
        try
        {
            using (inputStream = assetManager.Open(assetName))
            {
                return inputStream;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
 }
```

And then in your activity context access it like:

```
var Asset= context.GetFromAssets("AssetName");
```

Note that this will return a System.IO.Stream.

Good luck

Revert in case of queries.

Answer (score 0):

For Xamarin Android "NLog.config" (in this casing) in the assets folder will be loaded automatically. If the file name is different, then use:

```cs
LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration("assets/someothername.config");
```

Comment: Xamarin is slowly moving to NetStandard and is not always using the Android-specific-NLog-build.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. I resolved this issue by setting autoReload="false" throwExceptions="false". Due to these two my config file was not visible. I dont know how they affect the file visibility but setting above two to false i can get config file now
Thanks,

Comment: dou you set nlog.config  Build Action as an AndroidAsset